# Is it possible to have PayPal standard expand the 'Guest Payments' tab by default?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, opencart, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Standard to process orders. I have the "Paypal Account Optional" feature set to on, which makes it possible to accept payments from customers who dont have paypal accounts. OpenCart is the shopping system that i am using.

**This is the screen that is displayed when a customer want to purchase goods:**

[image]

**When you click the "Don't have a PayPal account?" link, the tab is expanded:**

[image]

**Is it possible to have this tab expanded by default, perhaps through the code that is sent to the site in the first place, with the order details?**

Comment: If it would be possible, PayPal wouldn't be safe anymore.

Comment: Why? The feature is still there

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365205/paypal-payment-standard-default-enter-card-details/19871549#19871549, sending an email to PayPal will also cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that PayPal stores a cookie when you log in. If you have a user on PayPal, it will show the "Log in" tab. If you have never used PayPal, or you have deleted the cookie, paypal will show the "Guest Payment" tab.

I can live with this, but it would still be nice to always have it show the Guest Payment by default.

Comment: This is not possible with PayPal Standard. If you were to start using PayPal Express Checkout, you can send the 'LANDINGPAGE=Billing' parameter in the SetExpressCheckout API call, which will take care of this for you.