# Paypal Payment Standard default enter card details

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payment, woocommerce

I'm sure this topic was here already but I just got off the phone with Paypal trying to find out if there is a setting on their accounts that would enable customers to see the "enter card details area" and not automatically (default set) direct you to log in/register to your paypal account. Paypal says there isn't a setting that would do that on their side but moo.com does just that when you checkout even if you are logged into paypal after their site transfers you to paypal site for payment it shows the enter card details area. So paypal claims it is rather something moo's site tells paypal to do and not the other way around. I know many sellers have the same issue with paypal turning away customers because of the way the checkout displays many shoppers conclude it is just for paypal account holders. Now I wonder if there is (or would be possible to create) a code for Maya to tell paypal (override it) and display the "enter card details" and not the log in/register as a default?

I'm very bad for explaining stuff so sorry it's so long. This is not something I demand it's just a thought that probably many of us had. Thanks!

Maggie

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question about WooCommerce PayPal standard support with a few hints as to what is needed.  Basically there are two things:

1. ensure that the PayPal Account Optional is On
2. Don't let WooCommerce send the user's email to PayPal

The email will cause PayPal to think the user has an account, so you use a WooCommerce filter to remove the email:

```
function smw_woo_paypal_args($args) {
    $args['email'] = '';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'smw_woo_paypal_args', 99);
```

Comment: This did not work for me when I added the code to my functions.php of my theme.

Comment: @travis I suspect Paypal has changed their system again.  This used to work, but I have seen cases where they send the client into Paypal hell even when no email is supplied.  My advice: use Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec) you can set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing to force the option of paying with a credit card rather than signing in to a PayPal account.

You'll also need to make sure that "PayPal Account Optional" is disabled in your PayPal account profile under Website Payment Preferences.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but that isn't the solution I'm looking for. Moo.com doesn't use express checkout and are able to send a code to paypal to have the second option open so there must be fairly simple solution to this. Never mind that there isn't a woocommerce extension for express checkout as far as I know.

Comment: Well you didn't look very hard then.  ;)  https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Did you try removing the email value like @Peter Wooster mentioned?  I'm curious if that does the trick.  In my experience those checkout pages have always been driven by cookies.