# Choosing which PayPal checkout form to use

Tags: paypal

We send people to PayPal to either donate or subscribe to our site.

We have guest access enabled, when you start a fresh session and navigate to our donate page and click the button, you get a nice 'guest' checkout page.

[image: Guest checkout form]

**But**, if you log in to PayPal and then logout again, you don't get this form on your next donate, you get the 'login' form.

[image: Login checkout form]

I'd like to be able to force all users to the Guest form if possible. I know that there are a bunch of features not available to us lowly 'donate button' users (as opposed to Express Checkout and the like) but surely I could pass a param that forced the Guest form?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

[Can you force PayPal Payments Standard API to show credit card fields first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309421/can-you-force-paypal-payments-standard-api-to-show-credit-card-fields-first)

[Is it possible to have PayPal standard expand the 'Guest Payments' tab by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087150/is-it-possible-to-have-paypal-standard-expand-the-guest-payments-tab-by-defaul)

Its all based on the PayPal cookie and there's nothing that allows you to override that.

**EDIT** This has been confirmed by PayPal support.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a cookie, or if you provide an email like WooCommerce does by default PayPal will assume you have an account.  See my answer in [Paypal Payment Standard default enter card details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365205/paypal-payment-standard-default-enter-card-details/19871549#19871549)